# GDB does not run correctly with roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, gdb, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to use GDB with roslaunch but I dont know how to. In the .launch file I write

```
<node pkg="read_kinect_01" name="front_end" type="read_kinect_01_node" launch-prefix="gdb --args" output="streen"/>
```

but whenever I try to use a command it does not work. If I run "r" (to run) it will run and display and error like it alway does (even when I am not using GDB). But whenever I try to write

```
break 54
```

I get a message saying

> No symbol table is loaded. Use the
> "file" command

If I try to run

```
print x
```

I get the same message.

After that I looked up "file" but was not able to find anything related to ROS that would help me. I tried

```
file /ROS/catkin_ws/devel/lib/read_kinect_01/read_kinect_01_node
```

among other attempts... but nothing (every single time :/ ). What exactly do I need to give to "file" so it will work?

*I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with ROS Indigo*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208913/gdb-does-not-run-correctly-with-roslaunch/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2015-05-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you compile your program with Debug symbols? `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2015-05-13**:
No, I did not. Works great now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @BennyRe commented, I needed to compile my program using:

```
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

---

Originally posted by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) with karma: 293 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-12**:
Please mark the answer by @BennyRe as accepted. He answered your question, so it is only fair.

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2015-05-13**:
@gvdhoorn First, I did put in name in the answer, so obvious I want to give credit where credit is due. Second, how did you make his "comment" to an "answer" ? I tried to do it but could not find out how (that's why I made the answer my self) :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-13**:
I didn't actually convert it, I just commented :). I'm not sure whether only moderators/administrators can do it, but it is possible.using one of the options under *more* (bottom right).

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2015-05-13**:
oh OK then, cool. Thanks in any case ;)